# Text colour of disabled textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a textbox where I have the enabled property set to false (as this are totalled figures I don't want to allow the user to focus on), and depending on the value in the field (whether it's negative or not) I set the text color to be red. Here is part of my javascript, which is called whenever any of the text that total up the disabled textbox changes

```
if (float < 0) 
obj.style.color = "Red";
}
else {
obj.style.color = "Black";
}
```

This works perfect in Chrome, but in IE the color doesn't change at all. I've looked this up online and people suggest setting Enabled="true" and ReadOnly="true", however when I do this the textbox can be focused on, so it messes up my tabindex. Could I somehow exclude these from my tabindex?

Comment: Why make the totalled figures a textbox at all, when you don’t want to let the user to edit it? It was in the 1990s when the only way to display results of client-side calculation was to use an input box...

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to add the appropriate styling.

```
if (float < 0) 
obj.CssClass = "Red";
}
else {
obj.CssClass = "Black";
}
```

in your aspx file add the styles for it

```
.Red{background-color: Red;}

.Black{background-color: Black;}
```

Using CSS you get complete control over your clientside styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting its `tabIndex` to `-1`;